# What are the benefits from each additional point of population?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6, what are the benefits from each additional point of population in a city?

I know the two most obvious ones: The number of districts you can construct goes up at certain intervals, and each population point means 1 more worker in the fields or in districts.

There are more subtle benefits, for example each city directly generates a small amount of culture and production based on its population.

That said, in general growing a large city for the sake of a large city seems rather pointless. It seems like you only truly benefit from a huge city if you later focus it on unit production, culture, science, etc depending on your victory goals, by tweaking the production priorities. But I could be wrong, hence the question.

Comment: I mean, growing large cities and tooling them towards your chosen victory path is the basic goal of the game. Not sure what else you are looking for in terms of benefit. There are times when smaller cities are more appropriate, and other times when large cities are more feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Citizens, the products of population growth, are producers as well as consumers. Each Citizen in a city produces 0.7 Science and 0.3 Culture per turn and can work one tile within the city's borders, adding its yields to the city. Citizens can also work as Specialists, filling slots in buildings in specialty districts and providing the city with additional Culture,  Science, Faith, Gold, and/or Production based on their role.

(http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Population_(Civ6))

There are also two Civics boosts that require a 10 and later 15 pop city to trigger.

Comment: Do not forget the population limit for districts.

Answer (score -2):

.7 science per pop is a great reason.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you may want to expand on your answer. It was likely downvoted lacking details.

Answer (score -3):

There are certain population breakpoints necessary to boost civics.

Comment: And what would those breakpoints be?  How does this answer the question?

Comment: Maybe this answer is referring to the inspiration moments (providing "boosts") for Civil Service ("grow a city to 10 population") and Urbanization ("grow a city to 15 population"). Those are valid considerations, but I meant something a bit more generic by the question.